# What is the most basic way to use an image using gtk in rust?

Tags: rust, gtk, rust-cargo

I'm new to rust and I'm trying to learn how to use GTK for a GUI application, however I don't know how to draw an image (.png/.jpg) in an application window.

```
extern crate gdk;
extern crate gio;
extern crate gtk;

use gio::prelude::*;
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Image, Window, WindowType};
use gdk_pixbuf::{Pixbuf, PixbufLoader};

fn main() {
    gtk::init().expect("Failed to initialize GTK.");

    let window = Window::new(WindowType::Toplevel);

    window.set_title("Image Viewer");
    window.set_default_size(400, 400);

    let image = Image::new();

    let pixbuf_loader = PixbufLoader::new();
    pixbuf_loader.write(&std::fs::read("path_to_your_image.png").expect("Failed to read image file"))
        .expect("Failed to load image");
    pixbuf_loader.close().expect("Failed to close PixbufLoader");
    let pixbuf = pixbuf_loader.get_pixbuf().expect("Failed to get Pixbuf");

    image.set_from_pixbuf(Some(&pixbuf));

    window.add(&image);

    window.connect_delete_event(|_, _| {
        gtk::main_quit();
        Inhibit(false)
    });

    window.show_all();

    gtk::main();
}
```

[I've tried the code above but I'm unsure how to fix the following errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Gw2.png)

Errors:

```
warning: unused import: `Pixbuf`
 --> src/main.rs:8:18
  |
8 | use gdk_pixbuf::{Pixbuf, PixbufLoader};
  |                  ^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

error[E0599]: no method named `get_pixbuf` found for struct `PixbufLoader` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:24:32
   |
24 |     let pixbuf = pixbuf_loader.get_pixbuf().expect("Failed to get Pixbuf");
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `PixbufLoader`

error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `Inhibit` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:32:9
   |
32 |         Inhibit(false)
   |         ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

warning: unused import: `gio::prelude`
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 | use gio::prelude::*;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors,](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77353477/edit) your question to include the error _as text_.

Comment: @Jmb I added the errors as text

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which GTK version you're using, so let's go over both GTK3 and GTK4

In GTK3, you can use [`gtk::Image::from_file()`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/git/docs/gtk/struct.Image.html#method.from_file) to immediately create a GtkImage from a filename.

In GTK4, there's a widget that is better optimized to show any image (rather than a basic image like an icon) called a `GtkPicture`. To create such a widget directly from a path, you can use [`gtk4::Picture::for_filename()`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk4/struct.Picture.html#method.for_filename)

Note that, if you're still learning, it might be good to check out the examples for both [gtk3-rs](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk3-rs/tree/master/examples) and [gtk4-rs](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/tree/master/examples) from time to time. There's also an [online book](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/book/) by the gtk-rs contributors.